# Too long filename prevents load of texture in three.js

Tags: three.js, textures

This is totally unbelievable. It is so that a man can go crazy. I was loading textures from a filepath like this:

pic/ekiFear.jpg

pic/ekiAnger.jpg

and so on...

The pathname is not even long but is nested into quite a deep directory if starting from the C:// or something like that. But that should not matter in this case since I am almost in the same directory?

However I had a couple of textures and the way I loaded them was indentical but only the "ekiFear"-texture loaded. The others didn't appear but there was no error message when trying to load them.

Anyway I shortened the filenames but this is madness. What if I had not had one texture with a short name. I would rip my hair before finding the problem. I don't think it should be like this. Should I send the code to MrDoob or is the problem something on my computer?

Comment: This problem did not occur to files loaded to the material the first time. Only when I updated the material and loaded a new texture on it.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: The length of the path should not matter unless you're going over 2000 characters or something, and then it's a browser issue... seems more likely there is another issue.

Comment: I have several files named index.html in the folder tree so I am also suspecting the browser is loading the wrong file even though the python server is supposed to only share the files in the current folder. It's just really strange though since i renamed it to be sure. But really, making the variable name a four letter string solved the problems and that was the only thing different in the code. It's just so bizarre and aggravating. Also putting it in a folder closer to C:// solved the problem so its a bit wacko.